# how to use material-icon in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify.js, mdi

I am trying to use material-icon in vuetify

By the way I am using vuejs via lighttpd

Therefore, you cannot use npm, require and import

Is there any way to use mdi?

I found a way to write css in material-icon url

But vuetify mdi is not available

Is there any way to use mdi?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you add a code? How you add Vue and Vuetify to project? How you try to use icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` to you `head`

and use just like `<v-icon>mdi-[icon name]</v-icon>`

Comment: @pleasehelp If this answer solved you issue, please accept it as answer in stackoverflow